# open office java extension undo and onStartApp method

Tags: java, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

I'm creating a java extension for open office and I need it to use the open office undo method.
I've found the documentation about XUndoManager but since I'm quite unexperienced with the API I don't know how to use it in my code.

Furthermore, I want this extension to do things before openning the document, I've found about onStartApp but, again due to my non experience, I don't know how to use it on my code.

Could someone help me ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

For Undo, use a dispatcher call as shown in listing 4.3 of [Andrew Pitonyak's macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php).

For [OnStartApp](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/document/Events.html), I did not find a lot of documentation.  Create a file called `Events.xcu` with code like the following:

```
<node oor:name="ApplicationEvents">
    <node oor:name="Bindings">
        <node oor:name="OnStartApp" oor:op="replace">
            <prop oor:name="BindingURL" oor:type="xs:string">
                <value>vnd.sun.star.script:events.py$OnStartApp?language=Python&amp;location=application</value>
```

Change the value of `vnd.sun.star.script` for use with Java, according to [this documentation](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Scripting/Scripting_Framework_URI_Specification).

Then add this to manifest.xml:

```
<manifest:file-entry
    manifest:media-type="application/vnd.sun.star.configuration-data"
      manifest:full-path="Events.xcu" />
```

The CTLO project at GitHub is an example of using [Events.xcu](https://github.com/portaildulibre/CTLO/blob/master/resources/Events.xcu) and [manifest.xml](https://github.com/portaildulibre/CTLO/blob/master/resources/META-INF/manifest.xml) in this way.

**EDIT**:

Here is an example of a dispatcher call in Java:

```
PropertyValue[] printProperties = new PropertyValue[1];
printProperties[0] = new PropertyValue();
printProperties[0].Name = "Print";
printProperties[0].Value = new Boolean(true);
XDispatchProvider xDispatchProvider = (XDispatchProvider)
    UnoRuntime.queryInterface (XDispatchProvider.class, xDesktop);
dispatcher.executeDispatch(
    xDispatchProvider, ".uno:Print","_self", 0, printProperties);
```

Comment: Why should all the documentation about open office  extension be for basic...
I don't find the equivalent of createUnoService or execute dispatch in java...

Comment: There are some examples around, such as the [XDispatch API page](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/frame/XDispatch.html).  But it does not seem to be as common for people who write Java code to use the dispatcher.  I edited my answer to show an example.  By the way, creating an UNO service is done with [XMultiServiceFactory](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/lang/XMultiServiceFactory.html) in Java.